# Multiple objects creation Tastypie POST XML

Tags: xml, django, tastypie

I'm trying to use HTTP POST requests to create new objects for a model, via Tastypie and in XML format. It works just fine for one element but whenever I try to create two or more, I'm getting errors.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

or

```
'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

The body of my request is as follow :

```
<objects type="list">
  <object>
    <field>'grrrr'</field>
  </object>
  <object>
    <field>'pfff'</field>
  </object>
</objects>
```

Answer (score 1):

To create several objects with tastypie you should use `PATCH` method in list context.

You should have both `POST` and `PATCH` in `list_allowed_methods`. xml you send looks fine to me (although I'm not familiar with tastypies xml serialisation)

[patch_list method docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#Resource.patch_list) from tastypie.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually I've moved past this particular obstacle by convincing the data owner to use json instead, PATCH was activated, though.. I'll look more into w/ possible.